# An experimental value for the amplitude of an electromagnetic wave

Tags: quantum-optics

I'm sorry if this question seems to be pretty easy or fool. I would like to know some experimental values for amplitudes of electromagnetic waves used in experiments of atom-light interaction. I have been looking for all internet, but I cannot find anything. I always find frequencies, but not amplitudes.

Comment: "some experimental values": in what kind of setup? Free space? Cavities?  What parameters do you know? Do you care about the typical amplitude of a laser, or of a single photon, ...?

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to calculate or estimate for yourself if you know the power and the cross section of the beam or wave guide: $P\approx \epsilon_0 E^2 Ac$ where $E$ is the peak amplitude of the electric field, $A$ is the area of the beam and $c$ is the speed of light. For the amplitude of the magnetic: $B\approx E/c$.

If you are also interested in the amplitudes in a resonant structure (cavity) of volume $V$ with a quality factor $Q$ that is fed by an EM wave of angular frequency $\omega$ and incoming power $P_{in}$: $P_{in}Q\approx \epsilon_0 E^2 V\omega$.

Update:
As suggested by @ZeroTheHero, I elaborate a bit why I prefer the approximate formulae above over trying to write an exact equation. In a propagating plane wave, you have the exact equalities: $P={\epsilon_0\over 2} E_0^2 Ac$ and $B_0=E_0/c$ where $E_0$ and $B_0$ are the maxima of the fields. In more complicated situations, however, even in a rectangular wave guide, fields are inhomogeneous in space with a different distribution (even their peak value, time average etc.), and they do have the same time dependence, either, but rather are phase shifted. What is more, this all depends even on the mode of propagation.

Comment: I upvoted but why $B\approx E/c$ rather than the strict equality $B=E/c$?  Are you implying something more than vacuum in the cavity?  Likewise for the use of the other $\approx$ signs...

Comment: @ZeroTheHero It is clear that in a cavity where the field distribution is inhomogeneous, the equality does not hold everywhere. Since I also did not define the exact propagation mode and position in the beam/waveguide (nor even the waveguide), equality may fail there, as well.

Comment: If you can update your answer accordingly it becomes a great answer.

Comment: Hi tif,I appreciate yout help. I do the calculations using the power of an ultraintense laser with 10^18 W cm^2  and I found an amplitude of the order of 10^12 N/C. Is that a reasonable answer?, I mean, Can that be the amplitude of a laser used, for example, to produce transitions in the electron of an atom?

Comment: Dear Carlos, sure, the calculated field is correct. And while realistic, this is extreme intensity and, as such, has extreme effects. If you consider even a dc field of $10^{12}$ V/m = 200 V/angström, it means that an electron picks up 200 eV when displaced by 1 A, which you would not call a perturbation. ;-)

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I have added an update according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The amplitude of the wave should be less important for absorption then the frequency of the photons, since the frequency determines the energy of the wave through $E=\hbar\omega$. If the photons have less energy then the required one, an increase in amplitude of the wave will do nothing as no photon will have enough energy to cause something to happened. I guess that with a higher amplitude, and thereby a higher intensity, one could more accurately determine let's say the concentration of a gas through absorption, but the individual photons will not be more inclined to cause an absorption then if you would have had lower intensity.

I hope this answered your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need the amplitude because, when you make a model of the interaction of an atom and a monochromatic plane wave, the probability of transition depends, not only of the frequency of the light, also of the amplitude.

Comment: @CarlosBeltran Okay, if this is the case you could do as tif suggested and try to get the intensity and measurementsetup and perhaps try to derive the amplitude?